# Angular 4. Необходимо вызвать метод дочернего компонента из родительского

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript, angular4

Есть два компонента. В родительском находится кнопка, в дочернем находится метод, который должен быть выполнен после ее нажатия. Как вызвать метод дочернего компонента в родительском?

Сейчас сделал кнопку в дочернем компоненте, событие нажатия на которую привязывается к нужному для выполнения методу. Нажимаю на кнопку получая ее объект по id в родительском компоненте. *Так вообще законно делать при использовании Angular?*

Comment: а как так оказалось, что метод обработки родительской кнопки оказался в дочернем элементе не связанном с кнопкой?

Comment: @Grundy кнопка должна вызывать модальное окно с формой. Код для открытия модального окна и само окно находится в дочернем компоненте

Comment: покажи как задается дочерний компонент

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй сделать все через сервис. Посмотри у [ng2-admin](https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin) сервис - GlobLStorage .Очень удобная практика для взаимодействия с компонентами. Нужно прописать его в 'providers' в твоем модуле.

P.S. Если будет трудно разобраться с сервисом, то могу предложить свою реализацию. Она более простая по-моему.

Answer (score 2):

Можно передать в дочерний компонент Observable, который будет по нажатию кнопки передавать новое значение из родительского (используй Subject).

PS: Но вообще архитектура какая-то подозрительная.